# Retrieve outstanding invoices with currency conversion complexity in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my Entity Framework application, I have an Entity called `Invoice.cs`, it has various properties, but here are the ones we're concerned about for the question:

```
public class Invoice : IEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public decimal Amount { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

I am attempting to query the database to get a list of all outstanding invoices. An outstanding invoice is the following:

> If the **total of the payments** made against the Invoice are **less than the Invoice Amount**, then the invoice is *Outstanding*.

I'm stuck on working out if an invoice is outstanding or not in my LINQ query, which currently looks like this:

```
var outstandingInvoices = from inv in _context.Invoices
    where !inv.IsDeleted && inv.Date >= startDate && inv.Date <= endDate
    select inv;
```

`startDate` and `endDate` are parameters passed in to filter the result.

Another complexity with this is to do with how payments are made. The payments can be made in RMB (Chinese currency) or GBP (UK currency), and in the report I'm generating, I want all to be displayed as GBP.

So I must somehow add this logic too:

```
// loop through payments for each invoice, and add payment
// amount to a local variable called total
if (payment.Currency == Currency.Gbp)
{
  total += payment.Amount;
} else
{
  total += payment.Amount / (decimal)payment.ConversionRate;
}
```

The `Payment.cs` entity has these two properties that are of concern:

```
public class PaymentViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public decimal Amount { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Payment Currency")]
  public Currency Currency { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Conversion Rate")]
  public float ConversionRate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: invoice amount is in GBP too, or it can be any currency?

Comment: For records that are in Gbp, is the `CoversionRate` 1?

Comment: Yep @RobertMcKee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have an issue because of the float/decimal differences.  Depending on your database provider, it might allow you to force the cast from decimal to float (or it might not).  Of course, then you'll have issues of payments that are really close, but not quite the same.  What if the amount / CoversionRate is 0.999999999999999999999999999 GBP when the amount was for 1 GBP?  Technically it's not fully paid.

Ultimately, the conversion rate should also be a decimal, not float, but determining the precision depends on your source.  Is it accurate to 5 decimal places or 7?

```
var outstanding = _context.Invoices
  .Where(x=>x.Date >= startDate)
  .Where(x=>x.Date <= endDate)
  .Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted)
  .Where(x=>x.Payments.Sum(p=>(float)p.Amount / p.ConversionRate) < x.Amount);
```

Alternatively if the total paid is within 1 GBP:

```
var outstanding = _context.Invoices
  .Where(x=>x.Date >= startDate)
  .Where(x=>x.Date <= endDate)
  .Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted)
  .Where(x=>x.Payments.Sum(p=>(float)p.Amount / p.ConversionRate) - x.Amount < 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator to adjust payment amount in case it is not in GBP:

```
var outstandingInvoices = 
       from inv in _context.Invoices
       let totalPayment = inv.Payments.Sum(p => 
               p.Currency == Currency.Gbp ? p.Amount : p.Amount / p.ConversionRate)
       where !inv.IsDeleted 
          && inv.Date >= startDate && inv.Date <= endDate                
          && totalPayment < inv.Amount
       select inv;
```

Comment: I get the following error where the cast happens. "Casting to Decimal is not supported in LINQ to Entities queries, because the required precision and scale information cannot be inferred."

Comment: @Ciwan there is no cast in my code. Where did you add it?

Comment: Where the division happens, cause ConversionRate is a float